# File won't save as .css (sublime)

Tags: css

I'm new to web development and I'm just starting to learn CSS. I am having a problem where I can't get any of the styling to work. At first I thought I didn't link back to the style sheet correctly, but now I'm seeing that my css file isn't saving as .css. I keep going to save as, select .css and then I go back to look for it under that file type and it's not there. When I click on it to view the properties in the folder, for the type it just says "file". I've tried several times to save it again as .css and nothing. Does anyone know what could be going on here?

Edit: I tried to save it as HTML now and it wouldn't work either. Everything new I am saving is saving as a plain "file" now and I don't know why.

Comment: What is the filename? The only thing I can think of is it is getting overwritten somehow.

Comment: It's just the name of the test site. I tried making a brand new file with a different name and still the same issue.

Comment: What operating system are you using? You may not have permission to write to files in the current directory you are in. I'm not sure, maybe creating the same file on the desktop to see if it's permissions related.

Comment: I got it, I had to add ".css" to the filename and save the type as "all files". No idea why that worked though... Now to get it to show up on my page

Comment: Glad you fixed it! This might be helpful for linking your CSS to your webpage: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp. Good luck in your web dev endeavours!

Comment: if you add ".css" and do not save as "all files", ".txt" is added as well, so you get: "file_name.css.txt"

Answer (score 0):

everytime you want to change the ending yourself, select "Save as", type the "file name + ending" and make sure always to check "Save as Type: All files".

You can also just type the "file name" and select the file type in "Save as Type: for example .css / .html"

Beginners' tip: If you are new to web development, I recommend the notepad. Every careless mistake that you notice here is golden for your future overall knowledge.